# How to read little endian integers from file in C++?

Tags: c++, c, binary, binaryfiles

Say I have a binary file; it contains positive binary numbers, but written in **little endian** as 32-bit integers

How do I read this file?  I have this right now.

```
int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[4];
    int num = 0;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","rb");
    while ( fread(&buffer, 1, 4,fp) != 0) {

        // I think buffer should be 32 bit integer I read,
        // how can I let num equal to 32 bit little endian integer?
    }
    // Say I just want to get the sum of all these binary little endian integers,
    // is there an another way to make read and get sum faster since it's all 
    // binary, shouldnt it be faster if i just add in binary? not sure..
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Byte swap during copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342527/byte-swap-during-copy)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: the question covers the same class of problem, but is different, I think. A beginner will find the linked question & answers difficult to follow.

Comment: If you are using a 80x86 machine - all of them uses little-endian - you won't need to make any adjustments to the numbers.

Comment: Several answers are assuming the *reader* is NOT little endian as well. The OP made no mention of that; only that the *writer* used LE-output format. The subject code should be portable to deal with either an LE or BE reader (which some are, thankfully).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one way to do it that works on either big-endian or little-endian architectures:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    int sum = 0;
    FILE *fp=fopen("file.txt","rb");
    while ( fread(bytes, 4, 1,fp) != 0) {
        sum += bytes[0] | (bytes[1]<<8) | (bytes[2]<<16) | (bytes[3]<<24);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is technically undefined behavior if the number you're reading in is negative, this can be avoided by casting `(unsigned) bytes[3] << 24`.

Comment: +1: for not assuming the reader is BE (though I would have gone 4,1 on the `fread()`)

Comment: @WhozCraig: Good point on the size vs. count arguments to fread -- changed.

Comment: do I need 0xFF after bytes[0]? like (buffer[0] & 0xFF) | (buffer[1] & 0xFF) << 8.. just curious, what bytes[1] will be if I have a number 123456. thx!

Comment: @user1713700: each element of bytes just holds one byte, and since it is unsigned, there's no need to mask off the upper bits, because they'll all be zero.

Comment: @VaughnCato I'm glad someone answered with this. There are several questions on SO about swapping endian-ness but your answer addresses the problem of "reading in a binary number as byte sequence of known endianness" in a cross platform and simple way.

Comment: There are a few fine points that makes this not fully portable. First of all `int` doesn't have to be big enough to hold a 32-bit value (there doesn't need to exist a type that holds exactly 32-bits at all). Second the `unsigned char` type doesn't have to be exactly 8-bits either.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using linux you should look [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/endian.3.html) ;-)

It is about useful functions such as **le32toh**

Comment: thanks a lot, but the other answer is more precise to my question

Comment: Can you expand this link-only answer? Add some example code for example.

Comment: I timed various methods. The linux library functions like le32toh and bswap_32 run 10x faster than bit-shifting arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

From [CodeGuru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?292902-C-General-How-do-I-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values):

```
inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)
{
    x = (x>>24) | 
        ((x<<8) & 0x00FF0000) |
        ((x>>8) & 0x0000FF00) |
        (x<<24);
}
```

So, you can read directly to `unsigned int` and then just call this.

```
while ( fread(&num, 1, 4,fp) != 0) {
    endian_swap(num); 
    // conversion done; then use num
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with short files, I recommend the simple use of the class stringstream and then the function stoul. The code below reads byte per byte (in this case 2 bytes) from an ifstream and writes them in hex inside a string stream. Then thanks to stoul converts the string into a 16 bit integer:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>   

using namespace std;

ifstream is("filename.bin", ios::binary);
if(!is) { /*Error*/ }
is.unsetf(ios_base::skipws); 

stringstream ss;
uint8_t byte1, byte2;
uint16_t val;

is >> byte1; is >> byte2;
ss << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << static_cast<size_t>(byte1);
ss << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << static_cast<size_t>(byte2);
val = static_cast<uint16_t>(stoul(ss.str(), nullptr, 16));

cout << val << endl;
```

For example if you have to read from a binary file, a 16 bit integer stored in Big Endian (00 f3), you put it inside a stringstream ("00f3") and then convert it in a integer (243). The example writes the value in hex, but it could be dec or oct, even binary, using the class bitset. The iomanip functions (setw, setfill) are used to give a correct format to the sstream.
The bad of this method is that it's tremendously slow if you have to work with files large in size.

Answer (score 0):

You read the code normally. However when you go to *interpret* the data you need to make the proper conversions.

This can be a pain in the butt as if you want to make your code portable, ie to run in both little and big endian machines, you need to handle all types of combinations: little to big, big to little, little to little and big to big. In the last two cases a no-op.

Fortunately this all can be automated with the [boost::endian library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html#conversion). An example from their documentation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

using namespace boost::endian;

namespace
{
  //  This is an extract from a very widely used GIS file format.
  //  Why the designer decided to mix big and little endians in
  //  the same file is not known. But this is a real-world format
  //  and users wishing to write low level code manipulating these
  //  files have to deal with the mixed endianness.

  struct header
  {
    big_int32_t     file_code;
    big_int32_t     file_length;
    little_int32_t  version;
    little_int32_t  shape_type;
  };

  const char* filename = "test.dat";
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
  header h;

  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(h) == 16U);  // reality check

  h.file_code   = 0x01020304;
  h.file_length = sizeof(header);
  h.version     = 1;
  h.shape_type  = 0x01020304;

  //  Low-level I/O such as POSIX read/write or <cstdio>
  //  fread/fwrite is sometimes used for binary file operations
  //  when ultimate efficiency is important. Such I/O is often
  //  performed in some C++ wrapper class, but to drive home the
  //  point that endian integers are often used in fairly
  //  low-level code that does bulk I/O operations, <cstdio>
  //  fopen/fwrite is used for I/O in this example.

  std::FILE* fi = std::fopen(filename, "wb");  // MUST BE BINARY

  if (!fi)
  {
    std::cout << "could not open " << filename << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  if (std::fwrite(&h, sizeof(header), 1, fi) != 1)
  {
    std::cout << "write failure for " << filename << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  std::fclose(fi);

  std::cout << "created file " << filename << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling and executing endian_example.cpp, a hex dump of test.dat shows:

```
01020304 00000010 01000000 04030201
```