# data access form *.BAD extension file of 4 GB

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, labview, endianness

I am doing a practical work using Labview and it stores data in *.BAD file format.
I need to access these data and want to process on that. But I don't know how to do it.

Probably I will do it with C++, any other suggestion are most welcome.
File size is of 4 GB.

-Mithil.

Comment: Do you have a link to a .bad specification? Or can you post a small file? If you have the LabVIEW code you can probably just open the source code of the code that writes the file.

Comment: I didn't find a file format, but this Oracle Control File Reference page indicates that a BAD file is created to store records that failed to load or caused an error during import. The BAD file is in the same format as the input data file to allow the user to make changes and resubmit     http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1005086

Comment: *.bad file is containing very big 1-D array. While opening that file one can see simply like: �?���?@��?@��?���?���?���?���?��?��?@��?��?@��?@��?��?��?@��?��?���?@��?@��?��?@��?��?@��?��?��?@��?@��?@��?���?���?@��?��?���?��?@��?@��?���?@��?���?@��?���?���?���?@��?@��?���?@��?���?���?@��?���?@��?���?���?@��?���?@��?��?���?���?���?���?���?���?@��?���?@��?���?���?@��?@��?���?��?@��?���?��?���?���?���?���?@��?��?���?@��?���?@��?@��?@�� Tell me if anybody knows how to decode it.

Comment: @PhilBrooks: that's not the same format the OP is using.

Comment: The `*.BAD` file seems to be binary data. The only way to decode it is by knowing how it was encoded and reversing that. I can't find any information on this `*.BAD` extension. I think that should be your first priority. If it is just raw data samples, then you need to know the data-type, (is it 32 bit floats, 64 bit doubles, 32 bit integers, etc).

Comment: @MithilParekh: if you can create a very minimal .bad file and upload it for us to play with, we might be able to make something of it.  Of course you should tell us what content you put into the file to speed up the reverse engineering.  :)  For example if it stores a 1D array, make one with the numbers 1 to 20 and let us see that.

Comment: Here is the small file.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ezd_iaHsQgSzMwcUYwZExITkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I referred -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001183/how-to-read-little-endian-integers-from-file-in-c -- but I need to get data with double precision float datatype.