# unexpected _mm256_shuffle_epi with __256i vectors

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I had seen [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7211519/3814202) on image conversions using `__m128i`, and thought I'd try and use AVX2 to see if I could get it any faster.  The task is taking an input RGB image and converting it to RGBA (note the other question is BGRA, but that's not really a big difference...).

I can include more code if desired, but this stuff gets quite verbose and I'm stuck on something seemingly very simple.  Suppose for this code that everything is 32-byte aligned, compiled with `-mavx2`, etc.

Given an input `uint8_t *source` RGB and output `uint8_t *destination` RGBA, it goes something like this (just trying to fill a quarter of the image in stripes [since this is vector land]).

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m256i *src = (__m256i *) source;
__m256i *dest = (__m256i *) destination;

// for this particular image
unsigned width = 640;
unsigned height = 480;
unsigned unroll_N = (width * height) / 32;
for(unsigned idx = 0; idx < unroll_N; ++idx) {
    // Load first portion and fill all of dest[0]
    __m256i src_0 = src[0];
    __m256i tmp_0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(src_0,
        _mm256_set_epi8(
            0x80, 23, 22, 21,// A07 B07 G07 R07
            0x80, 20, 19, 18,// A06 B06 G06 R06
            0x80, 17, 16, 15,// A05 B05 G05 R05
            0x80, 14, 13, 12,// A04 B04 G04 R04
            0x80, 11, 10,  9,// A03 B03 G03 R03
            0x80,  8,  7,  6,// A02 B02 G02 R02
            0x80,  5,  4,  3,// A01 B01 G01 R01
            0x80,  2,  1,  0 // A00 B00 G00 R00
        )
    );

    dest[0] = tmp_0;

    // move the input / output pointers forward
    src  += 3;
    dest += 4;
}// end for
```

This doesn't even actually work.  There are stripes showing up in each "quarter".

- My understanding is `0x80` should be used to create `0x00` in the mask

  - It doesn't really even matter what value gets there (it's the alpha channel, in the real code it gets `OR`'d with `0xff` like the linked answer).
- It somehow seems to be related to rows `04` to `07`, if I make them all `0x80` leaving just `00`-`03` the inconsistencies go away.

  - But of course, I'm not copying everything I need to.

What am I missing here?  Like is it possible I ran out of registers or something?  I'd be very surprised by that...

[image: Image with both parts of shuffle]

Using

```
_mm256_set_epi8(
    // 0x80, 23, 22, 21,// A07 B07 G07 R07
    // 0x80, 20, 19, 18,// A06 B06 G06 R06
    // 0x80, 17, 16, 15,// A05 B05 G05 R05
    // 0x80, 14, 13, 12,// A04 B04 G04 R04
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
    0x80, 11, 10,  9,// A03 B03 G03 R03
    0x80,  8,  7,  6,// A02 B02 G02 R02
    0x80,  5,  4,  3,// A01 B01 G01 R01
    0x80,  2,  1,  0 // A00 B00 G00 R00
)
```

[image: using the above shuffle instead]

Comment: You do `src  += 3` but you process only *one* thing per iteration, that's 2/3rds just gone

Comment: Yeah, I've omitted the code that does everything else for the sake of brevity.  That's what "one quarter" was supposed to mean x0

Comment: OK, not very clear. Anyway, `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` is not a generalization of `_mm_shuffle_epi8`, it acts like two `_mm_shuffle_epi8`'s side-by-side. So putting indexes like 16 and up is not useful.

Comment: Ah! I see, yes that seems to be the real problem here.  I added images but the rest of the code worked under the same (false) assumption...I will have to re-think this one then.  Thanks @harold!

Comment: Sometimes 256b vectors just aren't a win, especially if you need more than a `vpermq` at the end to correct for in-lane behaviour.  AVX still helps vs. SSE4.2 because of 3-operand instructions reducing front-end bottlenecks.  (Avoids a lot of MOVDQA instructions).  Intel Haswell and later (i.e. Intel AVX2 CPUs) only have 1 shuffle port, but can run 2 loads and 1 store per clock, so you often bottleneck on shuffle throughput for stuff like this.  Shifts or unaligned loads to replace shuffles can sometimes help.  (See Intel's optimization manual, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Ugh, I'm starting to get that now.  I've been benchmarking this along the way, the original `__m128i` post is only ~20 microseconds slower than my (really wrong) `__m256i` approach.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll leave the question open for a day to see if anybody has an idea of a good fix, but if not I'll just ask @harold to make his comment an answer ;)

Comment: OK how's this: load a 128b piece, then `vinserti128` the corresponding piece from the next iteration (inserting from memory does not count as a shuffle) and effectively use the SSSE3 version of the loop but with two iterations at once. Probably bottlenecked by stores though..

Comment: Good thought, though your suspicions were correct (I believe) in terms of saturation.  I didn't quite get a full version working, but performance was degraded after only getting half the rewrite through.  Perhaps I was wasteful with how I approached it, but I'm just going to stick with the 128bit version.  Please make your comment about `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` an answer so I can accept it, as that was the root problem with my code.  Thank you both for your thoughts and suggestions, this has been an informative experience!

Comment: Related: [What is the inverse of "\_mm256\_cvtepi16\_epi32"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49721807) re: how to work around the inconvenient design for unpack / repack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_mm256_shuffle_epi8` works like two times an `_mm_shuffle_epi8` side-by-side, instead of like a more useful (but probably higher latency) full-width shuffle that can put any byte anywhere. Here's a diagram from [www.officedaytime.com/simd512e](http://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/si.php?f=pshufb):

[image: vpshufb]

AVX512VBMI has new byte-granularity shuffles such as `vpermb` that can cross lanes, but current processors don't support that instruction set extension yet.

Comment: `vpermb` and `vpermt2b` will probably be worse throughput as well as latency :(.  `vpermt2w` on skylake-avx512 is 3 uops (p0 + 2p5), 7c latency 2c throughput.   https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64 for spreadsheets from IACA.  So in-lane + `vpermq` is at least as fast, and will get the job done in some cases.  (e.g. for `packsswb`.  It turns out `vpmovwb` is also 2 uops for p5, even though it's a 1-input shuffle that produces a half-width result.  All the `pvmov` shuffles are 2 uop except `vpmovqd`, the only one with a dword destination element size and truncation instead of saturation.)

Comment: `vpermt2d/q` are single-uop 3c latency on SKX, though.  In general it's only the lane-crossing small-element shuffles (including `vpermw`) that are more uops.  Maybe in the far future some CPUs will implement even the most complex as single-uop, or at least have more shuffle ports, but it will probably sometimes be worth it to use more instructions but fewer uops sometimes.  I realized recently that a shuffle with merge-masking gives you a limited form of 2-input shuffle, which is pretty damn cool (unless it takes an extra ALU uop to merge).  I haven't yet found any great use-cases, though.