# What is the inverse of "_mm256_cvtepi16_epi32"

Tags: x86, g++, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I want an AVX2 (or earlier) intrinsic that will convert an 8-wide 32-bit integer vector (256 bits total) into 8-wide 16-bit integer vector (128 bits total) [discarding the upper 16-bits of each element].
This should be the inverse of "_mm256_cvtepi16_epi32".
If there is not a direct instruction, how should I best do this with a sequence of instructions?

Comment: You probably want `_mm256_packs_epi32` with the original vector and a shuffled version of the same as inputs, then extract half of the resulting packed vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single-instruction inverse until AVX512F.  [`__m128i _mm256_cvtepi32_epi16(__m256i a)`  (`VPMOVDW`)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPMOVDW:VPMOVSDW:VPMOVUSDW.html), also available for 512->256 or 128->low_half_of_128.  (The versions with inputs smaller than a 512-bit ZMM register also require AVX512VL, so only Skylake-X, not Xeon Phi KNL).

There are signed/unsigned saturation versions of that AVX512 instruction, but only AVX512 has a pack instruction that truncates (discarding the upper bytes of each element) instead of saturating.

Or with AVX512BW, you could emulate a lane-crossing 2-input pack using `vpermi2w` to produce a 512-bit result from two 512-bit input vectors.  On Skylake-AVX512, it decodes to multiple shuffle uops, but so does `VPMOVDW`, which is also a lane-crossing shuffle with granularity less than dword (32-bit).  http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ has a spreadsheet of SKX uops / ports.

---

**The SSE2/AVX2 pack instructions like `_mm256_packus_epi32` (`vpackusdw`) do signed or unsigned saturation, as well as operating within each 128-bit lane**.  This is unlike the lane-crossing behaviour of `vpmovzxwd`.

You could `_mm256_and_si256` to clear the high bytes before packing, though.  That could be good if you have multiple input vectors, because `packs_epi32` takes 2 input vectors and produces a 256-bit output.

```
a = H G F E | D C B A    32-bit signed elements, shown from high element to low element, low 128-bit lane on the right
b = P O N M | L K J I

_mm256_packus_epi32(a, b)   16-bit unsigned elements
    P O N M H G F E  |  L K J I D C B A
      elements from first operand go to the low half of each lane
```

If you can make efficient use of 2x `vpand` / `vpackuswd ymm` / `vpermq ymm` to get a 256-bit vector with all the elements in the right order, then that's probably best on Intel CPUs.  Only 2 shuffle uops (4 total uops) per 256 bits of results, and you get them in a single vector.

---

Or **you can use SSSE3 / AVX2 `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`) to extract the bytes you want from a single input**, and zero the other half of each 128-bit lane (by setting the shuffle-control value for that element to have the sign bit set).  Then use AVX2 `vpermq` to shuffle data from the two lanes into just the low 128.

```
__m256i trunc_elements = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(res256, shuffle_mask_32_to_16);
__m256i ordered = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(trunc_elements, 0x58);
__m128i result  = _mm256_castsi256_si128(ordered);   // no asm instructions
```

So this is 2 uops per 128 bits of results, but both of the uops are shuffles that run only on port 5 on mainstream Intel CPUs that support AVX2.  That's fine as part of a loop that does plenty of work that can keep port0 / port1 busy, or if you need each 128-bit chunk separately anyway.

---

**For Ryzen/Excavator, lane-crossing `vpermq` is expensive** (because they split 256-bit instructions into multiple 128-bit uops, and don't have a real lane-crossing shuffle unit:  http://agner.org/optimize/).  So you'd want to `vextracti128` / `vpor` to combine.  Or maybe `vpunpcklqdq` so you can load the same shuffle mask with a `set1_epi64` instead of needing a full 256-bit vector constant to shuffle elements in the upper lane to the upper 64 bits of that lane.

Comment: I took your last suggestion and did this:
_mm256_castsi256_si128( _mm256_permute4x64_epi64( _mm256_shuffle_epi8( res256.m, shuffle_mask.m), 0x58)); with an appropriately defined "shuffle_mask".

Comment: @SteveBurns: yup, that's what I'd recommend for Intel CPUs if you only have a single vector to do at once, and can't make efficient use of 2x vpand / vpackuswd / vpermq to get a 256-bit vector.  For Ryzen, you'd want to `vextracti128` / `vpor`, because lane-crossing `vpermq` is expensive on Ryzen (which splits 256-bit ops into 128).